# How to create a stackedcolumn chart in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, charts

I'm having trouble understanding how to create a stackedcolumn chart in visual studio.
I have a datatable with employess, locations, and counts of sales.

```
[John | California | 35]
[John | Hawaii     | 10]
[John | Arkansas   | 12]
[Mary | California | 25]
[Mary | Hawaii     | 43]
[Mary | Arkansas   |  2]
```

I would like the employees along the x-axis and counts for each location for each employee stacked on top of each other with a label showing the counts for each location. I know how to do create a column chart for just the employees or just the locations, but I cannot figure out where to start with stacking them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use WPF and the development release of WPF Toolkit Charts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx. They have stacked charts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got no response (other than Vortex's comment - which btw, Visual Studio charts has stacked columns, I just wasn't sure how to use it because my graphs weren't coming out as expected), so I'll just discuss my workaround. First, I'd like to say that the main problem I kept running into was an alignment issue. In my hypothetical table above, I probably should have excluded the first row. The "error" that results comes from the fact that the data points would no longer be aligned. I tried chart.aligndatapointsbyaxis() method, but it still wouldn't align anything. I stumbled across the databindcrosstable() method, which is definitely helpful, but the alignment issue persisted. In the end, I decided not to use the optimal group by SQL query (i.e. select employee, location, count(*) Ct group by employee, location) because of the alignment issue (i.e. when not every employee has at least 1 count in each location). Instead, I created a datatable and ran multiple select count queries against each employee for each location. This way, I was able to get every location for every employee  because now I had a 0 values where they had no sales for that location. I realize that this is probably a terrible way to do it, but at least it works (although it takes a while to run). If anyone knows how I can make it work with my original group by query, please let me know. Thanks.